# Cross-platform encryption container library

Tags: c, encryption, cross-platform, filesystems

I have a need for a cross-platform (hopefully C) library that can create and mount encrypted filesystem containers. The same functionality of TrueCrypt but as a library so I would not have to externally include and invoke the Truecrypt executables.

Any alternate suggestions or solutions are also very welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [openSSL](http://openssl.org)

libssl supports a lot of popular cryptography algorithms. It also has wrapper methods for some (at least blowfish) which will simulate a stream cipher on a block cipher such as blowfish.

SYMMETRIC CIPHERS

```
blowfish(3), cast(3), des(3), idea(3), rc2(3), rc4(3), rc5(3)
```

PUBLIC KEY CRYPTOGRAPHY AND KEY AGREEMENT

```
dsa(3), dh(3), rsa(3)
```

CERTIFICATES

```
x509(3), x509v3(3)
```

AUTHENTICATION CODES, HASH FUNCTIONS

```
hmac(3), md2(3), md4(3), md5(3), mdc2(3), ripemd(3), sha(3)
```

http://openssl.linux-mirror.org/docs/crypto/crypto.html

Comment: Link is dead, this seems to be it: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/crypto.html

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple cross-platform C++ library (work name RC5Simple) for encrypting/decrypting files and byte arrays by RC5-32/12/16. May be it helpful to you.

Source and sample:

http://webhamster.ru/db/data/articles/157/rc5simple_1_23.zip

Tested on Linux-32, Linux-64, Windows-32, Windows-64, MacOSX, FreeBSD.

Official page: http://webhamster.ru/site/page/index/articles/projectcode/157 (rus).

You may easily include source files to your project. Licenses: GPL3 and BSD.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for an answer, but just as a reference: our [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/) is exactly what you describe.